# getting exact cell from output of windows command

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I run **netsh interface ipv4 show inter** command on win 2k12 server, it give me output like

```
Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 16           5        1500  connected     vEthernet (New Virtual Switch)
```

How i get that 16 Idx in a variable from output.
by findstr Idx its giving first row. Please give me solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean you want to get only the value 16 in a variable ?

Comment: yes .. you are right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that :

```dos
@echo off
For /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('netsh interface ipv4 show inter ^|find /I "1500"') do (
    set "Idx_Var=%%a" 
)
echo Idx_Var=%Idx_Var%
pause & exit
```